# Перехват событий QGraphicView

Tags: c++, qt5

Все с праздником! Итак, задача в следующем:

1. Расположить на `QGraphicsScene` предмет `QGraphicsItem`
2. Предмет `QGraphicsItem` должен уметь: вращаться вокруг своей оси, перемещаться мышкой, удаляться при нажатии на него ПКМ, должен иметь рандомный цвет.
3. `QGraphicsScene` должна уметь приближать и отдалять предметы, изображенные на ней

Собственно, первым делом я создаю обычный шаблонный `QWidget` (не буду выкладывать его код).

Далее, я создаю класс с предметом `QGraphicsItem`, в котором реализовываю все условия задачи по работе с предметом - перемещение предмета, рандомный цвет предмета, удаление предмета.

> MoveItem.h

```
#ifndef MOVEITEM_H
#define MOVEITEM_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QCursor>
#include <QRandomGenerator>
#include <QColor>

class MoveItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MoveItem(short typeItem, QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MoveItem();
private:
    QPainterPath path;
    QPen pen;
    QBrush brush;
    QRectF boundingRect() const override;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override;
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override;
    bool moving;
    int getRandomColorValue();
    int degree;
    short typeItem;
};

#endif // MOVEITEM_H
```

> MoveItem.cpp

```
#include "moveitem.h"

MoveItem::MoveItem(short typeItem, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent), QGraphicsItem()
{
    this->typeItem = typeItem;
    pen = QPen(QColor(getRandomColorValue(), getRandomColorValue(), getRandomColorValue()));
    brush = QBrush(QColor(getRandomColorValue(), getRandomColorValue(), getRandomColorValue()));

    path.moveTo(0, -30);
    path.lineTo(-20, 30);
    path.lineTo(30, 0);
    path.lineTo(-30,0);
    path.lineTo(20,30);
    path.lineTo(0,-30);
    path.closeSubpath();

    degree = 0;
}

MoveItem::~MoveItem()
{

}

QRectF MoveItem::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF (-30,-30,60,60);
}

void MoveItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    switch (typeItem)
    {
    case 0:
        painter->setPen(pen);
        painter->setBrush(brush);
        painter->drawRect(-30,-30,60,60);
        break;
    case 1:
        painter->setPen(pen);
        painter->setBrush(brush);
        painter->drawEllipse(-30,-30,60,60);
        break;
    case 2:
        painter->setPen(pen);
        painter->setBrush(brush);
        painter->drawPath(path);
        break;
    default:
        typeItem = 0;
        break;
    }

    update();
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(widget);
}

void MoveItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (moving)
    {
        this->setPos(mapToScene(event->pos()));
    }
}

void MoveItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        this->setCursor(QCursor(Qt::ClosedHandCursor));
        moving = true;
    }

    if (event->button() == Qt::MiddleButton)
    {
        this->topLevelItem()->setRotation(degree);
        degree < 360 ? degree += 10 : degree = 0;
    }
}

void MoveItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        this->setCursor(QCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor));
        moving = false;
    }

    if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        this->topLevelItem()->~QGraphicsItem();
    }

    Q_UNUSED(event);
}

int MoveItem::getRandomColorValue()
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution <int> dist(0, 255);
    return dist(*QRandomGenerator::global());
}
```

Вызываю в `QWidget` (главном окне) самую простую инициализацию QGraphicsScene и добавляю на нее предмет `QGraphicItem` с помощью класса выше.

> QWidget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->resize(800,600);
    
    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView (this);
    view->setGeometry(0, 0, width(), height());
    QGraphicsScene* gs = new QGraphicsScene(view);
    gs->setSceneRect(0,0,width(),height());
    gs->update();
    view->setScene(gs);
    MoveItem* it = new MoveItem(0);
    gs->addItem(it);
    it->setPos(width()/2,height()/2);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Все отлично работает! Осталось только добавить управление `QGraphicsScene`, а именно приближение/отдаление предметов на сцене. Для этого выносим в отдельный класс `QGraphicsView` в нем инициализируем сцену и перехватываем события `QGraphicsView`:

> Scene.h

```
#ifndef SCENE_H
#define SCENE_H

#include "moveitem.h"
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QList>

class Scene : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Scene(QWidget  *parent = 0);
    ~Scene();
protected:
    QGraphicsScene* scene;
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event) override;
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event) override;
    short typeItem;
private:
QList<MoveItem*> listItems;
};

#endif // SCENE_H
```

> Scene.cpp

```
#include "scene.h"

Scene::Scene(QWidget *parent): QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    typeItem = 0;

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);

    this->setScene(scene);
}

Scene::~Scene()
{

}

void Scene::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{

}

void Scene::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{

}

void Scene::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        if(scene)
        {
            listItems.append(new MoveItem(typeItem));
            scene->addItem(listItems.last());
            QPointF p = mapToScene(event->pos());
            listItems.last()->setPos(p);
            typeItem < 2 ? typeItem++ : typeItem = 0;
        }
    }
}

void Scene::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
{
    if(scene)
    {
        if(event->delta() < 0)
        {
            this->scale(1/1.05, 1/1.05);
        }
        else
        {
            this->scale(1.05, 1.05);
        }
    }
}

void Scene::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Plus)
    {
        this->scale(1.05, 1.05);
    }
    else if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Minus)
    {
        this->scale(1/1.05, 1/1.05);
    }
}
```

Изменяем инициализацию в головном виджете `QWidget`:

> QWidget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->resize(800,600);

    scene = new Scene(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

О чудо! не работают все перехваченные события из класса `MoveItem`:

```
QRectF MoveItem::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF (-30,-30,60,60);
}

void MoveItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    switch (typeItem)
    {
    case 0:
        painter->setPen(pen);
        painter->setBrush(brush);
        painter->drawRect(-30,-30,60,60);
        break;
    case 1:
        painter->setPen(pen);
        painter->setBrush(brush);
        painter->drawEllipse(-30,-30,60,60);
        break;
    case 2:
        painter->setPen(pen);
        painter->setBrush(brush);
        painter->drawPath(path);
        break;
    default:
        typeItem = 0;
        break;
    }

    update();
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(widget);
}

void MoveItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (moving)
    {
        this->setPos(mapToScene(event->pos()));
    }
}

void MoveItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        this->setCursor(QCursor(Qt::ClosedHandCursor));
        moving = true;
    }

    if (event->button() == Qt::MiddleButton)
    {
        this->topLevelItem()->setRotation(degree);
        degree < 360 ? degree += 10 : degree = 0;
    }
}

void MoveItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        this->setCursor(QCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor));
        moving = false;
    }

    if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        this->topLevelItem()->~QGraphicsItem();
    }

    Q_UNUSED(event);
}
```

В чем моя ошибка? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Надо в методах событий мыши класса Scene вызвать соответсвующие методы предка, чтобы он их переправил в сцену, и соответственно, в итемы

Comment: @так они разные совершенно по аргументам, как это сделать?

Comment: Базовые методы QGraphicsView надо вызвать в переопределенных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html):

> You can interact with the items on the scene by using the mouse and
> keyboard. QGraphicsView translates the mouse and key events into scene
> events, (events that inherit QGraphicsSceneEvent,), and forward them
> to the visualized scene. In the end, it's the individual item that
> handles the events and reacts to them. For example...

Перевод:

> Вы можете взаимодействовать с итемами на сцене при помощи мыши и
> клавиатуры. QGraphicsView преобразует соответствующие события в
> события сцены (которые наследуют QGraphicsSceneEvent) и передают их видимой сцене. В конце, события передаются соответствующему итему

Таким образом, чтобы это преобразование произошло, я думаю вам надо вызвать методы базового класса QGraphcisView при наследовании, то есть:

```cpp
void Scene::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

и так далее